# Azure DevOps ServiceHooks: Run Job state changed webhook

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webhooks

I am trying to use the service hook of azure devops, and while applying the the filter “Run Job state changed webhook”.
The pipeline running contains 8 jobs and when their states change none of them triggers the webhook and there is no attempt in the history of the pipeline. However when trying to test the service hook using the “Test” button, the attempt succeeds and the request is received normally.
Any ideas what might be the root cause of the problem and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue - have you made any progress on it?

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a solution?